# How do I rank this data by percentage and total possible?

Tags: sorting, charts, google-sheets, statistics

Given this set in Excel:

```
Group   Enrolled    Eligible    Percent
A       0           76          0%
B       10          92          11%
C       0           38          0%
D       2           50          4%
E       0           111         0%
F       4           86          5%
G       3           97          3%
H       4           178         2%
I       2           77          3%
J       0           64          0%
K       0           37          0%
L       11          54          20%
```

Is there a way to sort (for charting) to achieve the following order?

```
Group   Enrolled    Eligible    Percent
L       11          54          20%
B       10          92          11%
F       4           86          5%
D       2           50          4%
G       3           97          3%
I       2           77          3%
H       4           178         2%
K       0           37          0%
C       0           38          0%
J       0           64          0%
A       0           76          0%
E       0           111         0%
```

My goal is to rank/visualize using these criteria:

1. `Percent` desc (when `Enrolled > 0`)
2. `Eligible` asc (when `Enrolled = 0`)

After writing this question, the answer looks obvious: sort by `Percent` descending, then `Eligible` ascending (when `Percent or Enrolled = 0`). But I feel like I'm missing an obvious method/term to achieve the results I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With Google spreadsheet Query is the easy way. Goal 1:

```
=QUERY(A1:D13,"Select A,B,C,D Where B>0 Order By D desc,1")
```

Goal 2:

```
=QUERY(A1:D13,"Select A,B,C,D Where B=0 Order By C ,1")
```

Answer (score 0):

The term you're missing is [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)

Here's the formula you are looking for:

```
=SORT(A1:D13,4,0,3,1)
```

**Note**:
Numbers should be formatted as Numbers.

Comment: Note that this function is not available in other inferior spreadsheet solutions like Microsoft excel, which will require complicated solution based on a dead language like vba.